Same origin policy/CORS/csp errors and instagram errors with TOR
I've been using TOR browser for a few years, and I never experienced any problems. I used it to browse Instagram and other social media sites, and some other technical forums. However, since 2 months I've been experiencing some weird problems on these sites. Many sites don't load their content from another domains - for example tor.stackexchange.com works fine, but stackoverflow.com doesn't load its CSS from cdn.sstatic.net - I see just raw text, no content loads. In the javascript console there is this error - Content from <address> was blocked because of Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy header, see https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Cross-Origin_Resource_Policy_(CORP)# On other sites there are similar problems - I cannot login to Instagram anymore, the error in javascript console says: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The operation is insecure. Other sites do it as well: for example test.com doesn't load any content from api.test.com and in the error tab there are always errors related to Same Origin Policy/CORS/CSP and related stuff. These errors weren't present 2 months ago and before. I've been using two different version of TOR - one from 2019, which I've been using before these problems, and when they happened I switched to the newest version, but they persisted. When accessing these sites from normal firefox (without TOR) there are no such errors. In my 2019 TOR instance I have disabled any auto updates so there is no way that the browser updated something. These sites dont load also in the mobile android version of TOR. Now, the question is what is wrong? Did those websites changed something in their code or is this the tor browser's fault? It's weird because the 2019 instance worked one day and the next day there were those errors. How can I fix it to be able to browse these sites normally again? Can I disable all TOR security settings related to Same Origin Policy/CORS/CSP so the browser doesn't check for anything like that?

Same Origin Policy/CORS/CSP is a very effective defense method, and - it does more good things than bad ones for sure. A webmaster must specify what origins beyond it's website's domain are eligible for requests - so consult this part of the particular websites' functionality. As for Stack Overflow network - and this very site we're at particularly - I'm speaking about the Tor hidden service dot-onion address for years, but it's still not done regardless of the simplicity of the task. The problem is not browser-specific usually. However - Tor browser is tweaked up for privacy as a first priority - and it can be an issue in the case you're describing. Try using regular browser attached to Tor as SOCKS5s/SOCKS5h proxy - so no DNS queries will leak out. It will solve your case as I see it.
